# How to handle exception handling in singleton pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, exception, singleton

I am trying to understand how to handle exception handling here. I have my below Singleton class which connects to cassandra, initialize all the metadata on the first call and then starts a periodic background thread which updates all our metadata every 15 minutes.

```
public class CassUtils {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final CassSession cassSession;

  private static class Holder {
    private static final CassUtils INSTANCE = new CassUtils();
  }

  public static CassUtils getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private CassUtils() {
    CassConfig config = Utils.getConfig();
    try {
      this.cassSession = new CassSession(config);
      initializeMetadata(); // initializes metadata on the very first call
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // log error
      throw new IllegalStateException("cannot initialize metadata: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private void startScheduleTask() {
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata = getProcessMeta();
          List<ClientMetadata> clientMetadata = getClientMeta();
          List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata = getProcMeta();
          if (!processMetadata.isEmpty() && !clientMetadata.isEmpty())
            MetadataManager.setMetadata(processMetadata, clientMetadata, procMetadata);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log error
        }
      }
    }, 30, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }

  private void initializeMetadata() {
    List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata = getProcessMeta(true);
    List<ClientMetadata> clientMetadata = getClientMeta();
    List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata = getProcMeta();
    if (processMetadata.isEmpty() || clientMetadata.isEmpty() || procMetadata.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(); // is it ok to throw exception without any message here?
    }
    MetadataManager.setMetadata(processMetadata, clientMetadata, procMetadata);
    startScheduleTask();
  }
```

I need to notify the caller who is calling this singleton if there are any issues.

- Now for whatever reason if `CassSession` throws exception because that is the class connects to cassandra and for some reason it is not able to connect to cassandra (mostly it will never happen), then I catch the exception in `catch` block in `CassUtils` class and throw `IllegalStateException` to the users with a message in it.
- Also let's say if we are able to connect to cassandra through `CassSession` (which we will always) but in the `initializeMetadata` method, all our metadata are empty, then I don't want to proceed further so I am throwing `IllegalStateException` without any message in it. Is that ok? Because ultimately it will be caught by `catch` block of `CassUtils` class which is throwing exception to the calling users.

How to handle exception handling in singleton cases so that we can notify calling person whoever is calling this singleton. And `IllegalStateException` is the right exception to be thrown here? These above cases will happen during the first call at the initialization time. Is there any better way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using static / class initialization to create the `ClassUtils` instance.  As a general rule:

- All checked exceptions that are thrown in class initialization *must* be caught.  The compiler insists.
- Any unchecked exceptions that propagate out of a classes static initialization will ultimately cause an `Error` to be thrown.  Even in contexts where you are able to catch this error, you will be stuck with a class whose initialization has failed.  The JVM won't ever retry the initialization, and the class ... and any other class that depends on it will be unusable.

So, if you were to deal with this, you would need to catch and (appropriately) handle the exception *during* static initialization.

Next problem is that if you want to report the failure to users of the `CassUtils` singleton, then `getInstance()` has to return an instance of `CassUtils` (or maybe a subclass) that is capable of:

1. remembering the exception, or whatever that reported the failure, and
2. rethrowing it to the caller of instance methods on the `CassUtils` API.

That is possible, but complicated.

And IMO it is undesirable.  I think you would be best off NOT attempting to recover.  Treat failure to initialize the Casandra session as a fatal error.  If you can't do that, then the `getInstance()` method should be the method that throws / rethrows the exception that says "we are broken".  At least, that avoids the need for potentially any caller of any `CassUtils` method to have to deal with the "we are broken" exception.

---

Did anyone ever mention to you that singletons are a bad idea?  Consider using dependency injection instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How will `dependency injection` help me here? Just trying to understand the benefit I will get with that. If you can provide an example why DI will be better suited here with my example then  I have to think about removing all the singletons I have in my library.

Comment: Well, for a start, it avoids this kind of mess.  Second, it makes your codebase easier to test, and easier to reuse.  Google "singleton versus dependency injection"